# Почему jar запускается из среды и из консоли, но не запускается двойным кликом?

Tags: java, jar

Написал простую программу для теста:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class First {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) System.out.print(true);
        
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        
    }
}
```

<kbd>Java project</kbd>, версия 1.8, ничего не добавлял, просто назвал и создал. После этого тыкнул по <kbd>First.java</kbd> -> <kbd>Export</kbd> -> <kbd>Runnable JAR file</kbd>. там тоже ничего не менял, просто назвал

В Eclipse все запускается без проблем, через консоль с `java -jar название_файла` тоже, а двойным кликом не запускается

В переменные среды добавлены:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Другие `.jar` файлы, которые я скачивал с интернета, такой проблемы не имели, как и люди на ютубе. Как мне это исправить?

Comment: А что вы хотите увидеть, когда запускаете jar двойным кликом? Открытие некой консоли и вывод? Это так не работает, Надо сделать какое то UI для этого....

Comment: Как выглядит икона на файле jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы запускаете `jar` двойным кликом, то консоль не будет сама по себе открываться.
Если вы хотите, чтобы программу можно было открыть именно так, то есть 2 варианта:

1. Создать графический интерфейс (с помощью [swing](/questions/tagged/swing) или даже [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx)).
2. Создать пакетный файл, который будет открывать командную строку и прописывать запуск `jar`-ника. Тогда пользователь будет запускать этот пакетный файл, а не сам `jar`. Для ОС windows это будет .[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)-файл и выглядеть он будет так же, как будто вы запускаете `jar` из командной строки:

```
java -jar название_файла.jar
```